# Visual Studio 2010: Text-to-speech players

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, text-to-speech

Any recommendations on text-to-speech software that I can use with Visual Studio in Windows form application?

Comment: Are you looking for any specific feature or any TTS engine will do ?

Comment: @Susan what Sapi version are you running? and are you looking for free voices or voices to purchase?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/TTSinVBpackage.aspx) is the best option for text to speech using .Net.

Take a look at this link for [selection of voices](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10338925/voice.aspx)

Comment: guess I should have been more speicific - I was looking for options to have a broader selection of voices